# instanceof - javascript inconsistency in Object-Oriented javascript by Stoyan Stefanov

Tags: javascript, instanceof

In [Stoyan Stefanov's book Object-Oriented javascript](http://tinyurl.com/njxw55x), on page 103 he has the following.  However when I try this, I get a different result with `h instanceof Object`. Am I missing something, has something in JS changed since or is this an error in the book.

```
>>> function Hero(){}
>>> var h = new Hero();
>>> var o = {};
>>> h instanceof Hero;
true
>>> h instanceof Object;
false //true in Google Chrome
>>> o instanceof Object;
true
```

[image: Book excerpt]

[image: Google Chrome output]

Comment: Google Chrome command line.

Comment: It has to be `true` only. Where did you get it as `false`?

Comment: `h instanceof Object` should be `true`. I get that in Chrome and Firebug. Where do you get `false`?

Comment: I see `true` in the book on google books.  http://books.google.com/books?id=wUqP6sMFpK4C&pg=PT188&dq=h+instanceof+Hero&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HhuqUsepLofisAT_4YKQCg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=h%20instanceof%20Hero&f=false

Comment: @PSL - I added excerpt from the book. Looks like it may have been corrected in later versions then.

Comment: Why would i get a downvote on this?  This is a legitimate question, if there is/was an error in the book.

Comment: The version on google books is the second edition.  Seems he fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's what the book says, then the book
 is incorrect. (And searching the book content in Amazon.com confirms the error.)

Your `true` result that you get in Google Chrome is the correct result.

While the `h` object inherits from the `.prototype` on the `Hero` function, that `.prototype` inherits from the `.prototype` on the `Object` function. This means that `h` inherits both from `Hero.prototype` and `Object.prototype`, and is considered an instance of both constructors.

The only way it wouldn't be would be if `Hero.prototype` was an object that did not inherit from `Object.prototype`. But in that example, it uses the default object, so it does indeed inherit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the instanceof operator you don't test whether something was created by a certain constructor, but whether something inherits from a certain object (whether a certain object is in the prototype chain of something). foo instanceof F has exactly the same result as a recursive* `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === F.prototype`

```
var F = function() {};
var foo = new F();

foo instanceof F // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === F.prototype // true

F.prototype = {}; // changed the prototype of F

foo instanceof F // false
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === F.prototype // false

foo instanceof Object // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)) === Object.prototype // true
```

With that in mind, it is pretty obvious that if you don't change the prototype of a function to an object which doesn't inherit from Object.prototype, all the instances constructed with that function as constructor will inherit from Object.prototype, so they will be instances of Object.

```
F.prototype = Object.create(null);
var bar = new F();

bar instanceof F // true
bar instanceof Object // false
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

`instanceof` shim (just theoretical purposes, there is no practical use for it):

```
function instanceOf(object, constructor) {
  if (!object) return false;
  var object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
  if (object === constructor.prototype) return true;
  return instanceOf(object, constructor);
}
```